# How to avoid "antialiasing" effect in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Why does the following code changes line's width to 2 pixels instead of 1 eventually?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function clear() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function draw() {
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.scale(zoom, zoom);
  context.moveTo(100, 50);
  context.lineTo(100, 100);
  context.restore();
  context.stroke();
}

var zoom = 1.0;

$('#c').mousewheel(function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    zoom *= 1.1;
  } else {
    zoom /= 1.1;
  }
  clear();
  draw();
});

draw();
```

You can try it out here -- https://jsfiddle.net/818j0646/.

Just try to zoom in / out and you'll notice what I'm talking about:

[image]

How can I avoid this behavior? I need my line to stay 1 width always, without such "antialiasing" effect.

Comment: @Kaiido Why? I'm doing `restore` before the `stroke` call. Is it not enough?

Comment: ah missed that... apologies. You're right I would have expected it not to change. I'm on phone r.n Does the same occurs on multiple browsers? What happens when you change the scale while defining the path? What happens when you use setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) instead of save/restore?

Comment: @Kaiido It does so in Firefox and Chrome at least. Moreover, in Edge it blurred by default (zoom == 1.0)

Comment: @Kaiido "What happens when you change the scale while defining the path?" -- what do you mean?

Comment: @Kaiido "What happens when you use setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) instead of save/restore?" -- it has the similar issue -- https://jsfiddle.net/k8k43d9n/

Comment: Got back to my computer, and I can't repro on osX... I have no idea where it could come from... and for *"What happens when you change the scale while defining the path?"* I meant [this](https://jsfiddle.net/necp0cpf/), if the bug is consistent, both lines should have a different thickness

Comment: @Kaiido Well, it looks like this -- http://i.imgur.com/WwNQn7p.png

Comment: @Kaiido I can reproduce it even on Mac OS using Safari -- http://i.imgur.com/EZah0he.png

Comment: Ah you mean **this** ? This happens when you're not drawing on the pixel grid and is not related at all with the `scale` call... https://jsfiddle.net/bcry0oc6/ Not too much you can do about it, even svg has the same issue.

Comment: @Kaiido So that happens when I'm trying to draw something with coordinates not ending with .5 (like 1.0, 1.4, 1.6 etc)?

Comment: Well `.5` is a particular case, because it will make both *semi-pixels* the same density, so it will look nice to your eyes, `1.0` should not produce anti-aliasing and a single pixel will be used, every other value will use two pixels with different density, making it look *fatter* to your eyes. If you really want to avoid it, you have to make sure you're always on the pixel grid (some even prefer to be on the half-grid for thinner lines), but with your code, it sounds at least, very difficult.

Comment: @Kaiido "1.0 should not produce anti-aliasing and a single pixel will be used" -- are you sure? Because I thought that the canvas coordinate system uses .5 coordinates internally and it should draw three pixels on the screen when placed on 1.0 -- http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/i/canvas-half-pixels-1.jpg

Comment: Yes you are right : https://jsfiddle.net/bcry0oc6/2/

Comment: @Kaiido Ok, thanks for your example. What can I do then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add support for line-width relative to zoom (just make sure `restore()` is applied *after* stroke or all settings will return before anything is drawn):

```
var lineWidth = 1;                       // line width

function draw() {
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.scale(zoom, zoom);
  context.lineWidth = zoom * lineWidth;  // line-width * zoom
  context.moveTo(100, 50);
  context.lineTo(100, 100);
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();                     // restore last
}
```

**[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/818j0646/7/)**

If you want to keep about 1 pixel regardless of scale you can invert the line-width formula:

```
  context.lineWidth = 1 / (zoom * lineWidth);
```

**[Result](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/818j0646/8/)**

However, there will be small rounding errors affecting the anti-aliasing processing on some scales.

## Solution

The only real way to avoid this issue is to manually apply a matrix to points representing the line, make the values integers, then render the result of those as a line using the Bresenham or, IMO, the better and faster [EFLA](http://www.edepot.com/algorithm.html) algorithm and via `ImageData`, pixel-by-pixel, and finally push that to the bitmap. You can wrap all this into a single function of course.

This also mean you need to track the matrix. In newer browsers you can use `currentTransform` and soon `getTransform()` to obtain current transformation, or you can use a custom matrix solution for cross-browser and backward compatibility (there are many out there, here is [mine](https://github.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js)).

There is currently no way to turn off anti-aliasing for vectors rasterized to the canvas.

### Demo

I didn't implement boundary checks in this quick demo, but that is something you need to implement as well so the lines doesn't wrap around (ie. only draw if x >= 0 && x < width etc. .. per pixel).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var matrix = new Matrix();
var zoom = 1.0;

function clear() {
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function draw() {
  matrix.reset();  // replaces save/restore
  matrix.scale(zoom, zoom);

  // manually draw line via matrix and EFLA
  line(context, 100, 50, 100, 100);
}

// custom line function
function line(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {

  // instead of transforming context, apply matrix to points:
  var p1 = matrix.applyToPoint(x1, y1);
  var p2 = matrix.applyToPoint(x2, y2);

  // create a bitmap (for demo), or obtain an existing one (getImageData)
  var idata = context.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var data32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);
  
  _line(data32, p1.x|0, p1.y|0, p2.x|0, p2.y|0, canvas.width);
  context.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
}

// EFLA line algorithm
function _line(data, x1, y1, x2, y2, w) {

 var dlt, mul,
  sl = y2 - y1,
  ll = x2 - x1,
  yl = false,
  lls = ll >> 31,
  sls = sl >> 31,
  i;

 if ((sl ^ sls) - sls > (ll ^ lls) - lls) {
  sl ^= ll;
  ll ^= sl;
  sl ^= ll;
  yl = true
 }

 dlt = ll < 0 ? -1 : 1;
 mul = (ll === 0) ? sl : sl / ll;

 if (yl) {
  x1 += 0.5;
  for (i = 0; i !== ll; i += dlt)
   setPixel(data, (x1 + i * mul)|0, y1 + i, w)
 }
 else {
  y1 += 0.5;
  for (i = 0; i !== ll; i += dlt)
   setPixel(data, x1 + i, (y1 + i * mul)|0, w)
 }
}

// Set a pixel (black for demo)
function setPixel(data, x, y, w) {data[y * w + x] = 0xff000000}

$('#c').mousewheel(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    zoom *= 1.1;
  } else {
    zoom /= 1.1;
  }
  clear();
  draw();
});


draw();
  };
```

```css
body {overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/epistemex/transformation-matrix-js/master/matrix.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

**[As fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/818j0646/9/)**

Comment: OP's problem is just antialiasing, he wants the line to be 1px always, but because of scale, his drawing is often on floating pixels -> antialiasing artifacts.

Comment: In that case he could invert the scaling (`1 / (zoom * lineWidth);`). There will however be small rounding errors but closer to 1 px overall.

Comment: In any case, added a solution guaranteeing 1 pixel and no anti-aliasing. A little more performance hungry but the only way to get around anti-aliasing (for non-image graphics).

Comment: I can't test it right now but looks good to me :-), however if I'm reading correctly, this also means that there should be one empty canvas used only for this in case of painting over previous content right?